# MongoDB remove duplicates from a nested array

Tags: mongodb

I have a `users` collection with the following structure:

```
[
  {
    name: "xxx",
    labels: [
      {
        category: "Language",
        values: ["English", "Spanish"],
      },
      {
        category: "Hobby",
        values: ["Read", "Cook", "Read"],
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "yyy",
    labels: [
      {
        category: "Language",
        values: ["English", "English"],
      },
      {
        category: "Hobby",
        values: ["Read", "Play", "Play"],
      },
    ]
  },
]
```

I want to delete all duplicates from `values` array, so the result would be:

```
[
  {
    name: "xxx",
    labels: [
      {
        category: "Language",
        values: ["English", "Spanish"],
      },
      {
        category: "Hobby",
        values: ["Read", "Cook"],
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "yyy",
    labels: [
      {
        category: "Language",
        values: ["English"],
      },
      {
        category: "Hobby",
        values: ["Read", "Play"],
      },
    ]
  },
]
```

I tried to use `setUnion` and `setIntersection`, but I didn't know what is the right why to use them with a nested array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Mongo version 4.2+ you can use pipeline updates for this, like so:

```
db.collection.updateMany(
{},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      labels: {
        $map: {
          input: "$labels",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              {
                values: {
                  $setUnion: "$$this.values"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dl85vluW8MO)

For older Mongo versions you'll have to read each document into memory and do this in code, then update each document separately.